# Batch wall post to multiple Facebook accounts using php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post status messages to multiple FB users but not while they are on my site. I have publish_stream perms and a 60 day access token for each user I am posting to, but I can't figure out how to batch this correctly.

Is this the correct way to put in the access token?

```
$body = array(
            'message' => $message, 
            'link'    => $link,
            'picture' => $picture,
            'name'    => $name,
            'description'=> $description
            );
    $batchPost=array();
    $i=1;       
    foreach ($user_fb_id_array as $fb_id) {
        $batchPost[] = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'relative_url' => "/" . $fb_id['user_fb_id'] . "/feed?access_token=" . $fb_id['user_fb_auth_code'], // Will this work???
            'body' => http_build_query($body) );
        if($i++ == 50) {
            try {
                $multiPostResponse = $this->facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
            } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                echo("Batch Post Failed");
            }
            unset($batchPost);
            $i=1;
        }
    }

    if(isset($batchPost) && count($batchPost) > 0 ) {
        try{
            $multiPostResponse = $this->facebook->api('?batch='.urlencode(json_encode($batchPost)), 'POST');
        } catch(FacebookApiException $e){
            error_log($e);
            echo("Batch Post Failed");
        }
    }
```

To give credit where credit is due, this code was modified from the 25labs.com original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access token should be defined for each call at the same level as 'method' and 'relative_url' but your method there might work too.

Are you actually getting an error message or are you just asking how to implement this?